# Looking for a entry level program similiar to Microsoft Publisher?

Tags: microsoft-office

Sorry, I am brand new to Ubuntu. I am trying to locate a entry level Desktop Publisher program similar to Microsoft Publisher for my children to do Flyers, Posters, Cards, etc. Sorry with all these high tech questions to add something silly like this to the forum.

Answer (score 1):

Try out Scribus. It's a good desktop publishing software. It doesn't work with microsoft publisher files, but you can use it to do publisher type tasks.

Other software you can use for the flyers,posters,cards etc. would be gimp,inkscape, libreofice draw,xara (i think the free linux version has not seen any development for a while so you might want to avoid that one)

good luck (y)

Answer (score 1):

You can try Scribus

[Scribus](http://wiki.scribus.net/canvas/Download) brings open source award-winning professional page layout to Linux desktops, but also supports Windows and Mac OS.<sup>[Scribus](http://www.scribus.net/canvas/Scribus)</sup>

[Libreoffice 4](https://www.libreoffice.org/default/)

[VivaDesigner](http://software.viva.de/english/products/vivadesigner/) is a professional typesetting, layout and illustration software, with which complex graphic layout documents are created quickly and comfortably. Examples here are newspapers and journals, magazines, brochures and catalogs, books and all types of printed material.<sup>[VivaDesigner](http://software.viva.de/english/products/vivadesigner/)</sup>